# MATLAB : trainCascadeObjectDetector (line 245) Too many input arguments exception

Tags: matlab

in this code :

```
load('handFrontalClosedSession.mat');
imDir = fullfile ('/Users/aZahran/Desktop/TrainingSet');
addpath('/Users/aZahran/Desktop/TrainingSet');
negatives = fullfile ('/Users/aZahran/Desktop/negativeSet');
trainCascadeObjectDetector('stopSignDetector.xml',positiveInstances,negatives);
```

I changed some stuff in both folders, TrainingSet and negative Set, but the code was the same and it started throwing this exception, I reduced the data back to roughly their original sizes but not the same data, couldn't recognise the old ones from the new ones, but I think it has nothing to do with the data, any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is your MATLAB version? Can you open trainCascadeObjectDetector and see what is the line where the error occurs?

Comment: 2014b , it throws the exception at "catch e cleanUp(filenameParams); throw(e); end"

Comment: throw is probably throwing some other error captured. Can you step into this function in the debugger and see where the error occurs?

Comment: I cannot find any other errors thrown even with debugging the function !!

Comment: Interesting. What is filenameParams in the debugger?

Comment: its a 4x1 struct with the following filenameParams.outputXmlFilename:'stopSignDetector.xml', filenameParams.tempXmlFoldername:'stopSignDetector_trainCascadeTemp',filenameParams.positiveInstances:1x154 struct, filenameParams.negativeImagesFolder: '/Users/aZahran/Desktop/negativeSet'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72766/discussion-between-navan-and-user1712638).

Comment: any other thoughts from anyone else ?